# Not coming to your show / Not going to come to your show/ will not come to your show

Tags: tense, will-vs-going-to

> "I am not coming to your show ever again," said the actor after the interviewer asked him personal questions.

vs

> "I am not going to come to your show ever again," said the actor after the interviewer asked him personal questions.

vs

> "I will not come to your show ever again," said the actor after the interviewer asked him personal questions.

What's the difference?

As far as I know, the use of present continuous means the activity is going to happen in the near future or is scheduled. The use of going to refers to something that we have already planned before the time of speaking, so thusly the use of only will sounds valid to me, but I have seen even native speakers using all these 3 sentences, why is that so?

Comment: There is no difference in this context.  These are just different ways to express the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

In this context of matter there is no difference between the 3 expressions, they are merely different ways of saying the same thing.